# Twisted is blocking

Tags: python, python-2.7, asynchronous, rabbitmq, twisted

I am running into a problem whereby I have setup multiple consumers consuming from different queues using the twisted library.  This is all well and working, however it does not seem to continue execution of the main program, rather it just sits and waits and never hits my print statements after I call `reactor.run()`

Here is my main code where I actually call the consumers:

```
cc = InitSetup()
AsyncConsumerSetup(DeviceFeaturesConsumer('outboundMessaging', 'messaging', 'outbound', ws, 'registeredCallback', cc, connection), cc)
reactor.run()
print "starting to receive device"
ws.client.on('newDevice', receive_device)
print "end receive device"
```

here are the methods `InitSetup` and `AsyncConsumerSetup`:

```
def InitSetup():
    parameters = ConnectionParameters()
    cc = protocol.ClientCreator(reactor,
                                TwistedProtocolConnection,
                                parameters)
    return cc


def AsyncConsumerSetup(consumer, cc):
    try:
        d = cc.connectTCP("127.0.0.1", 5672)
        d.addCallback(lambda protocol: protocol.ready)
        d.addCallback(consumer.on_connected)
        d.addErrback(log.err)
    except Exception as e:
        print e
```

My understanding of twisted may be wrong, however I would have thought that the print statements and `ws.client.on` would have fired.

Comment: Yes your understanding of Twisted is wrong, but it happens to everyone when they learn.  Everything must run within the ``reactor`` loop.

Comment: notrorious, how would I go about moving that code into the reactor.

Comment: You basically have to make sure all your logic executes before ``reactor.run()``.  So if you move the ``reactor.run()`` to the end, it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing will run after `reactor.run()`, which is an event loop (a while loop in layman's terms). This is way your code is blocking.  The idea is to have all your code execute in the event loop.  One way you could do it would be to take your code that executes the consumers, put it into a function, remove the `reactor.run()`, and call it when the `reactor` starts

```
def InitSetup():
    parameters = ConnectionParameters()
    cc = protocol.ClientCreator(reactor,
                                TwistedProtocolConnection,
                                parameters)
    return cc


def AsyncConsumerSetup(consumer, cc):
    try:
        d = cc.connectTCP("127.0.0.1", 5672)
        d.addCallback(lambda protocol: protocol.ready)
        d.addCallback(consumer.on_connected)
        d.addErrback(log.err)
    except Exception as e:
        print e

def initFunction():
    cc = InitSetup()
    AsyncConsumerSetup(DeviceFeaturesConsumer('outboundMessaging', 'messaging', 'outbound', ws, 'registeredCallback', cc, connection), cc)
    print "starting to receive device"
    ws.client.on('newDevice', receive_device)
    print "end receive device"

reactor.callWhenRunning(initFunction)
reactor.run()
```

This will be your main module.  Unfortunately, I don't know enough of your code to test it though.